# One topic with 4 queues, only one be consumed

Tags: java, rocketmq

There are some RocketMQ topics, but only one topic with 4 queues, only one queue be consumed.

RocketMQ 4.2.0
Java 1.8

The consumer group configuration:

```java
    depthConsumerGroup.setNamesrvAddr(rocketMQConfig.getNameServers());
    depthConsumerGroup.setConsumeThreadMin(64);
    depthConsumerGroup.setConsumeThreadMax(128);
    depthConsumerGroup.setAdjustThreadPoolNumsThreshold(500);
    depthConsumerGroup.setMessageModel(MessageModel.CLUSTERING);
       depthConsumerGroup.setConsumeFromWhere(ConsumeFromWhere.CONSUME_FROM_LAST_OFFSET);
```

When I reset topic timestamp, and restart application. The all queue will be consumed.But run for a while, only one queue will be consumed.

Comment: what means "reset topic timestamp"?

Answer (score 0):

#### check 2 things:

- check have you send some orderly message to one queue.  others empty. so you can only consume 1 queue
- check rule: all-consumer-instances in-one-consumer-group must have same pub-subs(consumerGroup-topic-tag must be the same, or queues can not be asigned right)